# Storing and calling method in a Map with generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to learn a bit of what I consider more complex Java, I got interested in Generics as I noticed it can do amazing things.
I thought about doing this:
Have a Map that will store a class and some form of method, this would be used so in case of giving a certain class, lets say `String.class` it would run the code inside the method.

I saw it being done and working on a project called [ACF](https://github.com/aikar/commands/blob/f6a8c68d80ad295a3b506b2fbb9eec59c6999fc5/core/src/main/java/co/aikar/commands/CommandContexts.java) (Aikar command framework).

An example of how it manages to register the new method:

```
registerContext(char.class, c -> {
    String s = c.popFirstArg();
    if (s.length() > 1) {
        throw new InvalidCommandArgument(MessageKeys.MUST_BE_MAX_LENGTH, "{max}", String.valueOf(1));
    }
    return s.charAt(0);
});
```

His register method seems simple being just:

```
// The map
protected final Map<Class<?>, ContextResolver<?, R>> contextMap = new HashMap<>();
// The register class
public <T> void registerContext(Class<T> context, ContextResolver<T, R> supplier) {
    contextMap.put(context, supplier);
}
```

I tried making something similar but yet I couldn't really understand.
I am whiling to do more research, but at this point I don't know what to search for. I don't know what this type of method storage or method declaration is called.
I watched a few videos and read a few posts about the generics in Java but mostly stay very basic which I manage to understand, but still can't figure out how this works.
The results I expect is to be able to for example call `contextMap.get(class).run()` and it would invoke the method.

**edit**:
PS: I'm not asking anyone to write code for me or do this or that, just to point me in the right direction to learn and I'll do the rest myself. Or maybe some small explanations about generics.

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted seems to be related to reflection. The Java tutorial has a whole chapter about generics. if you want to learn about them, you should read that. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

Comment: @JBNizet I'll trad it thank you. And sorry I removed reflection from it, thought it was included in the generics part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8 there are few functional interfaces that help with this kind of functionality: `Function`, `Supplier`, `Consumer` and `Runnable` (which is older).

`Runnable` is simply a piece of code to run, no input, no output. You probably have seen it before: to create a new `Thread` you need to provide a `Runnable` and then the new `Thread` invokes that code. `Supplier` is something similar, but it returns a value. `Consumer` accepts input, but it does not return anything. `Function` has both input and output, in your example something similar is used.

So basically, depending on what you want, you can create a map of methods, where key is the name of the method and value is a runnable (piece of code to run) - `Map<String, Runnable>`.

```java
Map<String, Runnable> methodMap = new HashMap<>();
methodMap.put("say hello", () -> System.out.println("Hello"));
methodMap.put("say goodbye", () -> System.out.println("Goodbye"));

methodMap.get("say hello").run();
```

All this has a little to do with generics, but imagine you wanted to store methods with input and output, that would become problematic. You would need something like `Map<String, Function<?, ?>>`.

Comment: Yeah I want it to have input and output if possible. For example, I'd register a method to given a string will return a number, then give it a string and get the number from it based on which class I pass to the map. But I'll look into functions as it seems to be what I need!